# Get the file name from Css propery background url

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.icon-displayer').css('background-image');
console.log(a)
```

gives me value as `url("http://localhost:8080/myApp/icons/xing-square.png")`
from this string i want extract only the file name i.e **xing-suare.png**  how do i do it?

I tried

```
var url= $('.icon-displayer').css('background-image');
var filename = url.split('/').pop()
```

did not work

Comment: did you check what you actually get in the url variable? the split should work, check what it returns  before calling pop on i

Answer (score 3):

Javascript `pop` method remove the last element from an array. Use `split` and then get the last position of the array.

```
var url= $('.balaIconPicker-icon-displayer').css('background-image');
var array = url.split('/');
var filename = array[array.length - 1];
```

Comment: filename: xing-square.png")   dont want bracket also

Comment: You could replace `")` with nothing. `filename = filename.replace('\")', '')`. Maybe a regex should do this better but im not good with regex.

Comment: `filename = filename.replace(/\"?\)/, '')`  using regex

Answer (score 0):

If there are no parameters, then Lucas's answer is okay and it's the one you should use. However if the string at the end is something like "test.php?id=125" you will get the "?id=125" too which may not be what you want. A regular expression can save you from this:

```
var url = "http://www.test.com/directory/test.php?id=128",
    cleanRegexp = /\/([^\.\/]+\.[a-z]{0,3})[^\/]*$/;
var result = cleanRegexp.exec(url);
window.alert(result[1]);
```

the regular expression finds the last slash, then looks after it for anything that isn't a slash or a dot, then grabs the dot and the extension, finishing before any special characters.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/89j8v2xo/)